# how we manage selectednodechanged event for different node for different functionality in tree view control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void FolderStructure_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

this is the event which is used for click event of any node of treeview control but i want to set different functionality on different child node of treeview?
please help me to know how can i identify which node is clicked by user?
please help ...

Comment: You can do `sender as TreeNode` to get the clicked node.

Comment: thank you ...but i cant understand how can i do that ...can you please explain it by code....please help.

Comment: I've added an answer based on my comment. Is that enough for you to move forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
protected void FolderStructure_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var treeNode = sender as TreeNode;
    /* Do stuff with `treeNode` */
}
```